# Suction from flowing water

Tags: pressure, water, vacuum

My memory from physics says yes but I want to check.
Our pool is dirty and our vacuum is broken. If I were to stick the vacuum hose into the pool drain, would the flow of water going into the drain away from the opening cause a partial vacuum in the hose I could utilize to suck dirt from the pool?  The suction doesn't need to be much, just able to suck loose dirt. The pool is 13 ft but depth shouldn't matter with the head pressure of the pool.

Comment: James, check out [siphoning](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=siphon+water&hl=en-GB&gbv=2&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAUQ_AVqFQoTCPbCpOzhj8gCFcGWLAodt2cE2A).

Comment: I know about siphoning and this should be the same but here I am using water flowing past an opening to pull a vacuum

Comment: Though now that I think about it as long as the hose is in the gutter that would be lower than the water surface and that would allow a siphon to happen.  I didn't think about it like that.

Comment: Assuming that since your pool is 13ft deep, it's a commercial pool & not a backyard pool; further, my guess is that you had a separate, portable pump & filter to use for vacuuming? If I'm right on those, then I don't believe that the main drain would be strong enough to use for vacuuming, you're better off just getting the broken one fixed.

Comment: On Thursday I stuck a garden hose into the drain about 2 feet below the pool water level.  The siphon was strong enough that when right at the bottom of the pool it could suck up sand, but not from further than half an inch.  What I found worked well was to kick up the dirt and let the cloud get sucked up.